# the size of my text file is 25 bytes, according to ftell. However, when I use ftell as the size of a char array, sizeof gives me 200. what gives?

Tags: c, arrays, file, io, sizeof

Essentially, this is my problem.

```
FILE *fp = "/my/textfile/location";
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
int size = ftell(fp);

char *output_string[size];

printf("%d", size); // gives me 25
printf("%ld", sizeof(output_string)); // gives me 200.
```

Why does sizeof(output_string) give me 200 when the int returned from ftell is 20?

Comment: 200 == 25*8. 8 == sizeof(char*).

Comment: Jules - There is probably duplicate on "how to declare array of char [dynamically]"... if you do know already than it's simply "typographical error"...

Comment: An array of char* is not an array of char.

Comment: do you mean *output_string[size] is creating an array of pointers instead?

Comment: `FILE *fp = "/my/textfile/location";` -- That compiled for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *output_string[size];
```

This is array of pointer, if you are running in 64-bits machine,
one pointer is 64-bits, which is 8 bytes.
if size is 25, then :

```
sizeof(output_string) = 25 * sizeof(char *) = 25 * 8 = 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me.

I accidentally wrote * in my array declaration, which made output_string an array of pointers, not chars